# Unable to create oracle table through Jenkins Job

Tags: sql, oracle, jenkins

I am trying to create a new table using a Jenkins job that calls a sql file. I am able to manually create the job in the database (using the below syntax), however when attempting to create via the Jenkins job I get the following error: **ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword**

This is the syntax:

```
--task number
--@author
--My Name
--12/12/2017
-----------.
--*  Target Environment: IFO Schema
---------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    MY_TABLE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SSN                 VARCHAR2(9 BYTE),
    BOARD               VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
    LICENSE_NUMBER      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    EXPIRE_DATE         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    NAME                VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    COUNTY              VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
    CASE_NUMBER         VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
    DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    REPORT_CLASIFIER    NUMBER,
    JOB_NAME            VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
    CHECK ( JOB_NAME IN ( 'M','R' ) ) ENABLE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( MY_TABLE_ID )
  );
```

Does anyone know if this is a known issue with Jenkins? or if I need to change the syntax to be accommodated via the Jenkins process?

Comment: will depend on your implementation through Jenkins, however I know the implementation I have used that does a similar thing would not work if you had a semicolon.  Not sure what error it gave now but may be something to try.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Getting ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword. I did try your recommendation and the same error has occurred.

Comment: Just a little background. My Jenkins job calls a powershell script that then searches for sql files within a specified directory on the Jenkins workspace. Not sure if you have a similar configuration.